# Splitting root symbol

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

How can the `\sqrt` command be modified to split root symbol into two or more lines automatically?

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
        The \textbf{Euclidean distance} between two points $P=(x, y, z)$and $Q=(a, b, c)$
        in space is defined as $d(P, Q)= \sqrt{(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} + (z - c)^{2}}$.
        The distance between a point $P$ and a geometric object $S$ like a line or plane is
        the minimal distance $d(P, Q)$ which is possible with $Q$ on $S$.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: have]

And I want something like this (artificial example using `\overline`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
        The \textbf{Euclidean distance} between two points $P=(x, y, z)$and $Q=(a, b, c)$
        in space is defined as $d(P, Q)= \sqrt{(x - a)^{2} +}$ $\overline{(y - b)^{2} + (z - c)^{2}}$.
        The distance between a point $P$ and a geometric object $S$ like a line or plane is
        the minimal distance $d(P, Q)$ which is possible with $Q$ on $S$.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: want]

Comment: Can you not afford a display-math environment in your document? Your square root would be easier to parse in one.

Comment: There is something strange with the space between the coordinates `x,y,z` of the point `P`.

Comment: @Jubobs: That's intended to be an inline equation.

Comment: Another (peripheral) thing: do you really intend to have two plus signs back-to-back, under the square root?

Comment: You could have provided the codes for the two examples (MWEs), to save people trying to help you some time ;)

Comment: @m0nhawk Don't inflict that to your readers, please.

Comment: @m0nhawk I agree with egreg; if I was reading that in the context of a textbook, I end up re-writing the equation on a separate piece of paper just to comprehend what was going on.  The equation (at least the general form) is certainly important enough to warrant the extra space of `displaymath`.  It's a good question, I would just consider whether or not it's a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's not a good idea (I think so too), but first of all, this is a TeX.SE and this is an interesting question as I think. And automatic splitting can be useful not only for roots, but for a `\overline` and `\underbrace` features.

Comment: @m0nhawk Oh, of course!  I didn't say it wasn't a good question - it's a great question!  (egreg and) I just would rework the actual content, but that's a design choice and is ultimately left up to you. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This version allows TeX to break the math automatically. In this version you can only do this once a full version would need a counter and generate new unique names for the points each time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\savepos#1{\leavevmode\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\string\save@#1{{\the\pdflastxpos sp }{\the\pdflastypos sp }}}}

\def\xx#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo\csname save@#1\endcsname}
\def\yy#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo\csname save@#1\endcsname}


\def\xsqrt#1{%
\sqrt{\vphantom{#1}}%
\ifx\save@L\@undefined
\else
\ifdim\yy{L}=\yy{R}%
\else
\rlap{$\overline{\vphantom{#1}\hskip\dimexpr\xx{b}-\xx{L}\relax}$}%
\fi
\fi
\savepos{L}#1\savepos{R}%
\ifx\save@L\@undefined
\else
\ifdim\yy{L}=\yy{R}%
\llap{$\overline{\hskip\dimexpr\xx{R}-\xx{L}\relax}$}%
\else
\llap{$\overline{\vphantom{#1}\hskip\dimexpr\xx{R}-\xx{a}\relax}$}%
\fi
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}



    \savepos{a}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
        The \textbf{Euclidean distance} between two points $P=(x, y, z)$ and $Q=(a, b, c)$
        in space is defined as $d(P, Q)= \xsqrt{(x - a)^{2} +(y - b)^{2} + (z - c)^{2}}$.
        The distance between a point $P$ and a geometric object $S$ like a line or plane is
        the minimal distance $d(P, Q)$ which is possible with $Q$ on $S$. 
    \end{minipage}\savepos{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are a wizard?  This is fantastic!

Comment: You have a little bug in your code: when `\yy{L}=\yy{R}` then the `\vphantom{}` is missing in the code. And another problem: the `\sqrt` mark have discrete sizes, maybe it doesn't vertically fit with `\overline` (try to use `\bigl(` inside the formula). Better would be: `\def\myoverline#1#2{\vbox{\hrule\kern-.4pt\hbox{$\vphantom{#1}\hskip#2$}}}`.

Comment: @wipet thanks yes probably, looks about right (once I'd remembered what this answer was doing at all:-)

Answer (score 18):

In cases such as the one you've brought up, I believe it's both simpler (for you) and clearer (for your readers) if you don't use the "surd" symbolism at all. Instead, use `[...]^{1/2}`, as is done in the following modified form of your MWE. Alternatively, as others have already suggested as well, you could move the long term into a "displayed" equation, i.e., onto a line by itself.

Not only is `[...]^{1/2}` simpler for you (because you don't have concern yourself with where the line break may fall), it is also easier on the readers' eyes (i.e., less distracting and hence also clearer) since the interline spacing in the paragraph in question doesn't have to be adjusted to accommodate the "surd".

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
The \textbf{Euclidean distance} between two points $P=(x, y, z)$ and 
$Q=(a, b, c)$ in space is defined as $d(P, Q)= [(x - a)^{2} +(y - b)^{2} 
+ (z - c)^{2}]^{1/2}$. The distance between a point $P$ and a geometric 
object $S$, such as a line or plane, is the minimal distance $d(P, Q)$ 
which is possible with $Q\in S$.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a typo: `1/2`.

Comment: @Sigur - thanks, I've fixed the typo

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone} % change it to your class!

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
A   = \sqrt{a+b+c} \\
    \overline{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}+d+e+f}\\
    \overline{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}+g+h+i}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

### Just another example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it to your own document class!
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
d(x,y)  
    = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2} \\
        \overline{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}{}+(y-y_0)^2}\\
        \overline{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}{}+(z-z_0)^2}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not so easy to handle with `\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}`.

Comment: It seems to me that this is the same manual tweak as what m0nhawk does in the question. The problem is how to make it automated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution. When you need, just use the new command and split the radical as you want.

```
\newcommand{\sqrtx}[2]{\sqrt{#1}\\\overline{#2}}

here some text \dotfill$\sqrtx{x^2+y^2}{z^2+y^2}$
```

[image]

Comment: Although, it would be better to have TeX decided where this break should take place.

Comment: @SeanAllred but TeX's aesthetic judgement would say never break here, so leaving it for TeX to decide can't really work:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Points, you have good ones, but is it not possible to `trick' TeX?

Comment: @SeanAllred anything is possible

Comment: @SeanAllred see another answer:-)