# Problem with { and } when splitting equation into two lines

Tags: equations, amsmath, split

I am using the following equation which works perfect when it is a single-line equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{NPIF}^\ast_i \mathrel{\mathop:}= \sum_{j=1}^{\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{L}} \biggl\{ w_{\mathrm{L},j} \, \tilde{l}_j \left[ \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_+ \right]}_{ij} \, \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,max},j}^{\left[ k_+ \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} + \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_- \right]}_{ij} \, \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,min},j}^{\left[ k_- \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} \right] \biggr\}
\end{equation}
```

I would like to break this equation into two lines using the `split`environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \mathrm{NPIF}^\ast_i \mathrel{\mathop:}= \sum_{j=1}^{\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{L}} \biggl\{ w_{\mathrm{L},j} \, \tilde{l}_j \left[ \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_+ \right]}_{ij} \, \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,max},j}^{\left[ k_+ \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} \\
    + \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_- \right]}_{ij} \, \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,min},j}^{\left[ k_- \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} \right] \biggr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The last code gives me a `! Extra }, or forgotten \right.` error. I tried to close the two brackets in the first line by using `\right. \right.` and a corresponding `\left. \left.` on the second line but this did not solve the error... Any ideas?

Comment: Left right constructions cannot be broken. Scale the fences manually using the four big levels. Then breaks are supported. Btw: next time please post a full minimal example next time. That makes it a lot easier for others to help.

Comment: You can also use `\left{ \right.` or `\left. \right}` where the `.` (dot) closes a `\left \right`pair without printing it. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380641 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `\left` in one line and the matching `\right` in the other one: this is not allowed.

Also, there's no need that outer parentheses are larger than inner ones; in this case `\Big` size is enough; also the square brackets are in the same size for ease of reading. The alignment point can be at “PDTF”, in order to exploit the symmetry.

I introduced a shorthand for `\mathrm`; a more semantic command is better anyway (change the name into one that suits you best). I'm not sure about `\mathrm` applied to the exponent `n_1`, though. I'm also dubious about the usefulness of the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\rv}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rv{NPIF}^\ast_i \coloneqq
  \sum_{j=1}^{\rv{N}_\rv{L}}
    \Bigl\{
      w_{\rv{L},j} \tilde{l}_j
      \Bigl[ & \rv{PTDF}^{[k_+]}_{ij} (x_{\rv{L,max},j}^{[ k_+]} )^{\rv{n}_1} \\
    {} + {}  & \rv{PTDF}^{[k_-]}_{ij}( x_{\rv{L,min},j}^{[k_-]})^{\rv{n}_1} \Bigr] \Bigr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your case you want to break the line at the + sign.  Therefore you have one open `\left` in the first line and an open `\right` in the second line.

So you need one `\right.` in the first line and one `\left.` in the second line (see the marked lines `<========` in the following MWE).

The following MWE compiles with no errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{NPIF}^\ast_i \mathrel{\mathop:}= 
    \sum_{j=1}^{\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{L}} \biggl\{ w_{\mathrm{L},j} \, \tilde{l}_j 
    \left[ \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_+ \right]}_{ij} \, 
    \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,max},j}^{\left[ k_+ \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} 
    + \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_- \right]}_{ij} \, 
    \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,min},j}^{\left[ k_- \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} \right] \biggr\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \mathrm{NPIF}^\ast_i \mathrel{\mathop:}= \sum_{j=1}^{\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{L}} 
      \biggl\{ w_{\mathrm{L},j} \, \tilde{l}_j 
      \left[ \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_+ \right]}_{ij} \, 
      \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,max},j}^{\left[ k_+ \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} 
      \right.\\ % <=====================================================
    + \left. % <========================================================
      \mathrm{PTDF}^{\left[ k_- \right]}_{ij} \, 
      \bigl( x_{\mathrm{L,min},j}^{\left[ k_- \right]} \bigr)^{\mathrm{n}_1} \right] \biggr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which of course have issues if the material of the two parts does not have the same height. Just leaving this comment for others who come by.