# Splitting a Minimization Equation into More than 2 Lines

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, split, multline

I'm working with a particularly hairy minimization problem that I would like to split into at least three lines. Here's some sample code so you can follow me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[long]{optidef}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\min_{\mathbf{\widetilde H}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } \\ &{\left[ \sum\nolimits_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}|}(Y_{it} -L_{it}-\sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q}X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}-\gamma_{i} - \delta_{i} - V_{it}\beta)^2\right]}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So, what we have here is a decent start. And perhaps I'd accept it, *if* it were the end of the equation. The full equation is

```
&\min_{\mathbf{\widetilde H}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } \\ &{\left[ \sum\nolimits_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}} 
\frac{1}
{|\mathcal{O}|}(Y_{it} -L_{it}-\sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q}X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}
-\gamma_{i} - \delta_{i} - V_{it}\beta)^2
+ \lambda_{L}\|\mathbf{L}\|_{\ast}+ \lambda_{H}\|\mathbf{H}\|_{1,e} \right]}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The code still compiles, but it still looks awkward. What if I wanted to split it into three lines? Or, what about 5? My next attempt was

```
&\min_{\mathbf{\widetilde H}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } \\ &{\left[ \sum\nolimits_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}|} \\ &(Y_{it} -L_{it}-\sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q}X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}-\gamma_{i} - \delta_{i} - V_{it}\beta)^2+ \lambda_{L}\|\mathbf{L}\|_{\ast}+ \lambda_{H}\|\mathbf{H}\|_{1,e} \right]}
```

but when I try this, I get `! Missing } inserted. <inserted text>  }`

What am I missing here? I've tried nesting split and optidef, as well as optidef and multline, but I haven't been able to split this into more than two lines. I know there must be a simple solution to this, but I'm new to LaTex and have never needed to split before. Thanks so much!.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch happy to be here. Any idea how I can split this equation further?

Comment: you are not using optidef at all, just loading the package. for split like all ams alignments you can have as many lines as you wish, ending each with `\\ `  You have not said what errors you got, perhaps the issue is the spurious `{....}` that you have around the terms after `&` which will prevent any line breaking?

Comment: Did you saw the related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383572/16550 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with `aligned` on two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[long]{optidef}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf{\widetilde H}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } \Biggl[ \sum_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}}
\frac{1}
{|\mathcal{O}|}\biggl(Y_{it} -L_{it}-\sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q}X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}
-\gamma_{i} - \delta_{i} - V_{it} \beta\biggr)^{\!2} \\[-2ex]
{} + \lambda_{L}\|\mathbf{L}\|_{\ast}+ \lambda_{H}\|\mathbf{H}\|_{1,e} \Biggr]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico to make it different to mine:-)

Comment: @Mico: I tried both sizes to check which was preferable, and it seems I had a copy-paste accident . As often, I forgot to check. I'll fix it within seconds. Thanks for warning me!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; Lol  ; o )

Comment: @Mico:  done, mylord! Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: +1 for equalizing the sizes of the parentheses. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much indication of what you want the result to be, here is one possible layout, which like your example code just uses `amsmath` and not the `optidef` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[long]{optidef}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{\widetilde H}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } 
\left[
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}} 
\frac{1}
{|\mathcal{O}|}\bigl(Y_{it} -L_{it}-\sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q}X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}
-\gamma_{i} - \delta_{i} - V_{it}\beta\bigr)^2\\
&+ \lambda_{L}\|\mathbf{L}\|_{\ast}+ \lambda_{H}\|\mathbf{H}\|_{1,e}
\end{aligned} \right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{\widetilde{\mathbf{H}}^\ast, \mathbf{L}^\ast, \delta^\ast,\gamma^\ast } 
\biggl[ \, \sum_{(i,t) \in \mathcal{O}}\frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}|}
\biggl(
&Y_{it} -L_{it} - \sum_{p=1}^{P} \sum_{q=1}^{Q} X_{ip}H_{pq}Z_{qt}
  -\gamma_{i} \\
& -\delta_{i} - V_{it}\beta \biggr)^{\!\!2}
 + \lambda_{L}\|\mathbf{L}\|_{\ast}+ \lambda_{H}\|\mathbf{H}\|_{1,e} \, \biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```