# Splitting a root within a root

Tags: math-mode

I have to typeset the following unwieldy formula (the formula for the length of the side of the regular 17-gon):

```
\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2\sqrt{17 + 3\sqrt{17} + \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}
```

splitting it to get an effect analogous to the following:
[image]
(due to narrow text columns).

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111347/10898 ?

Comment: Thanks, @azetina. I had a look at that, but the double overlines, together with the further root signs, give completely different spacings, and I don't know how to pad some space between an overline and what's under it.

Comment: Please, don't do it! :-)

Comment: Don't worry, @egreg, I don't intend to (unless the deadline rumbles too close). That's why I asked this question rather than looking into the underbelly of \overline. :-)

Comment: if it has to break, I'd use `(...)^{\frac{1}{2}} rather than `\sqrt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution based on `trimclip`. Usage

```
\hsplit[<betweeen left and right>]{<width of first part>}{<stuff>}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\hsplit}[3][\par]{%
\clipbox{0em 0em #2 0em}{#3}#1
\clipbox{{\the\dimexpr\width-#2\relax} 0em 0em 0em}{#3}}
\begin{document}
pft pft \hsplit[\par\hspace{7em}]{15em}{$\displaystyle\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2\sqrt{17 +
3\sqrt{17}+ \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}$} pft pft
\end{document}
```

[image]

It just splits the box into two parts, you only need to dial the width at which the box is to be split.

Comment: +1. Just out of idle curiosity: What is "pft"? :-)

Comment: @Mico It is a `p` followed by an `f` followed by a `t`, and, more importantly, a modern alternative to `zzz`. Happy New Year!

Comment: Many thanks for the thorough explanation. :-) Happy New Year to you as well!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Happy New year to you...

Comment: I was a bit unresolved, but I'm accepting this answer for its greater versatility and for having let me know about trimclip.

Answer (score 6):

*Ad hoc* solution, with visual formatting. I added the long formula just for comparison.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{$
\dfrac{1}{4} \sqrt{34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2\sqrt{17 + 3\sqrt{17} 
+ \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}}$}

\begin{multline*}
\frac{1}{4}\textstyle
\sqrt{34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2\sqrt{17 + 3\sqrt{17}\rule{0pt}{10pt}\ }\ } \\
\textstyle
\overline{\rule{0pt}{17pt}
  \overline{\rule{0pt}{13pt}
    + \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}
  \ }
\ }
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy new year. I have voted the previous comment and the excellent answer. For my humble opinion split a root is very ugly.

Comment: @Sebastiano Happy new year! Yes, that's not the best way to do it; an alternative could be to place the long expression in a two-column float.

Comment: Happy New Year to both `egreg` and `Sebastiano`

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, great workaround!

Answer (score 3):

I must confess that I find it quite challenging to read expressions with up to four [4!] nested surds -- with or without line breaks.

I suggest you consider replacing the outer two surds with `(...)^{0.5}` and `\bigl[...\bigr]^{0.5}` expressions. Doing so will also allow LaTeX to find suitable line breaks *automatically* if the formula is typeset in inline math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\setlength\textwidth{2.75in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
%first, inline math
\noindent
$\frac{1}{4} \bigl[34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2(17 + 3\sqrt{17} 
+ \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}\,)^{0.5}\bigr]^{0.5}$

%second, display math
\begin{gather*}
\tfrac{1}{4} \Bigl[34 - \sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}} - 2\bigl(17 + 3\sqrt{17} \\
+ \sqrt{170-26\sqrt{17}} - 4\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}\,\bigr)^{\!0.5}\,\Bigr]^{0.5}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Happy New year to you...

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I find it challenging too, but rewriting it with a 1/2 exponent is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_symbol.  Unfortunately, it did not say when mathematicians realized `\sqrt(x)=x^{1/2}`.

Comment: Why the downvote?